# Quarkus POST multipart JSON fruit

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jax-rs, quarkus

I followed this Quarkus tutorial:

https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients

Is it possible to post multiple fruit in a single multipart request to the 'create' endpoint defined in the tutorial?

It would be possible to define a fruit collection such as List or Fruit[], or FruitBasket that wraps such a collection, and post a JSON object that embeds a list of fruit.  However, it seems that the proper HTTP way is to use multipart.  Could the Quarkus or JAX-RS team explain how to support multiple JSON objects of the same type?

An example javascript (possibly jquery ajax) client to post multiple fruit in a single request would also be useful.

Comment: Can you add an example of what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried any of your own suggested solutions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.